# can't install any gem using Aptana

Tags: ruby, aptana, aptana3

I have installed the latest `Aptana Studio 3`, build: `3.6.0.201407100658` and when I try to install gems, I get the same error message.

For example, from terminal window: `gem install bundler`

The error message:

```
Couldn't find a valid gem 'bundler' (>=0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - SSL_Connect returned=1 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
(https://api.rubygems.org/latest_spec.4.8.gz)
```

Any help with this since I am stuck with this error.

Comment: Occasionally the HTTPS server is down temporarily or inaccessible, for whatever reason. It should reappear soon. If it's been inaccessible for a day, and you can't access it via a browser, then perhaps there is a networking connection problem on your side that needs to be investigated. While Aptana is a decent editor, it's preferred to do your gem manipulations from the command-line. Using the command-line will become a big part of your life developing using scripting languages, so you should get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

This error,

```
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - SSL_Connect returned=1 
state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
(https://api.rubygems.org/latest_spec.4.8.gz)
```

is because you are using the `https` version of the rubygems source. Try this

```
gem install bundler -s http://rubygems.org
```

By using the `http` source, you can work around this

**Method 2**

Change your gem sources by entering the following two commands

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

The first command will remove the secure connection
The second command will add the insecure connection, allowing you to bypass this warning

Then you can run

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: No, do not remove the HTTPS source. That was put in place for very good reasons. *IF* the OP is willing to accept the possibility of hacked connections, the HTTP version of the site could be acceptable, but in general don't do that. Instead, be patient and the HTTPS site will come back online. If it seems like a permanent problem, then possibly there are networking/gateway/firewall issues that need to be address. Using the HTTPS server is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this when starting to use Ruby on Rails with Aptana. Didn't get exactly the same error message, but it was an issue with the installation of the bundles.

Another person might find this helpful, so I thought that I would add that for me, all it took was running:

```
gem update --system
```

And then, as answered in the previous answer:

```
gem install bundler
```

=)